# 404 error for Api Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

URL: http://localhost/WebApp/api/values and this is hosten in iis 10.

[image: 404 error for api controllers][image: Directory structure]
[image: Global.asax.cs]

Getting this error only for api controllers. Checked the configs are all fine. I created another api project and same error for that also.

Comment: You should show the configs even if you say they are fine.

Comment: Please share your project tree / structure

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hey guys thanks all your support. The issue was with routing. As i had created virtual directory `localhost/WebApp/api` for api and also routing was configured `api/{controller}/{id}` . So it was unable to find the values api controller  at `localhost/WebApp/api/values` .

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your WebApi routes in Register method of `WebApiConfig.cs` as

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And then call this method in `Application_Start` as

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Also, your Controller should inherit from `ApiController`

I would suggest to create a folder called `Api` inside your Controllers folder and add all the WebApi controllers there keeping it separate from Non WebApi controllers.

Comment: Yes, these configs are present in the `WebApiConfig.cs ` and i am calling `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);` in `Application_Start`

Comment: Can you post your WebApiConfig.cs content

Comment: If your WebApiConfig.Register is similar to what I have posted then you don't need to mention WebApp in the Url

Comment: Yeah its same as your code. Is there any issue with asp.net and .net framework version issues?

Comment: Have you tried creating a separate folder called Api inside Controllers folder

Answer (score 0):

Hey Debasis I am also working with web api and I faced the same error many times. The reason behind the error I find out was that I was calling an 'httpPOST' api in view, whereas, 'httpPOST' is used to insert or update the data in the database. 
I think that you are also stuck in the same problem, My suggestion is that create a 'httpGET' api for the same and call that 'httpGet' api in place of 'httpPost'. 
I hope that will resolve your problem.

Comment: No dear i am  making get request only. Its a Get() method by default.